# Do I need to make my own frame handling and caching logic or are there built in functions?

Tags: python, cache

I've been working on a physics sim and I have basic timestep function and length constraints working. However, i've been using a workaround to force blender to update each step - i'm not using blender's timeline but I need to.

Do I need to write the frame handling and caching logic myself or does blender have an api for that? For example, I want to run my update() function each frame and then be able to move the playhead back and forward through the frames that have already been simulated.

Blender 3.6 and above mark the timeline blue where frames have already been simulated. Is this behavior available to addon makers?

many thanks

Comment: i recommend telling us your "big goal" what you wanna achieve. For me it sounds like a very complicated solution for a problem which might be much easier to solve.

Comment: I think the question is fair. For example [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/279350/60486) (and in a link to another Python solution there), I were recreating cache in Python, but without using any dedicated API for that, and without adding a visual indicator on the timeline. It would be nice to have such an option (or know about it, if it already exists…)

Comment: My goal is to write my own physics simulation, like the one blender has and I would like to interact with it in the same way. I would like to be able to hit play and the simulation caches the frames it processes and i can scroll back and forward through them, just like blender's physics sim